# Instrument facilitated leg lengthening?

Tags: height

I'm no doctor nor expert in human bodies but I have a theory that if human body can be transformed / reinforced by long term physical exercises because of its nature in responding to the environment / survival requirements, can the legs be lengthened by instruments that implement a 30 minutes adjustable force to stretch the legs every day? For a year or two?

Would the bone actually be responsive thus growing itself accordingly? Even adults? Is there anyone here with the science or medical career of orthopedics to please give any insights on this?

I would really want to make something like this if it's scientifically 50% possible. Growing taller is the lifetime dream of A LOT of people. They can give anything for that.

Or is there already a product like this?

If it's possible, what could be some unwanted side consequences?

Any potential problems or risks?

Comment: Do a web search on "growth plates" and you'll have your answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you! Have anyone done any experiments on instrument facilitated limb lengthening on long term? Any documents about this?

Comment: I don't know if anyone has done research on your question but I doubt it because if you read the information I suggested by searching for "growth plates" you would know that lengthening bones in adults is impossible.

Comment: There is work on building artificial growth plates so who knows what might happen but apart from bone lengthening surgery just stressing the bone won't work due to the fused epiphyses.

Answer (score 1):

Though adults can't grow anymore, as was explained by previous answers, cosmetic bone lengthening does exist.
Simply explained, the surgeon breaks the bones and slowly extends the gap between the bone fragments as they heal. [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4182395/)

There is little scientific evidence about the risks of this procedure, as it rarely done in the western world. But beside the regular surgical risks of wound infections, there is the risk of infection of the materials and non-union of the bones. Nerves could be damaged by distention and the range-of-motion of the lengthened limb could be limited by complications.

Comment: That's definitely not what I'm after. It's not worth it.